# C program crashes when a function is called.

Tags: c

So, I ask the user for novo->prato (a list item), but somewhere in the function call or the scanf before it, the program crashes and I can't see what is wrong with the code.

These are the declarations and the function.

```
typedef struct pedido pedido, *ppedido;

struct ingrediente{
    char nome[15];
    int id;
    int qtd;
    int limite;
    int consumo_medio;
};

struct item{
    char id[5];
    int ing[10];
    float qtd[10];
};

struct pedido{
    char id[5];
    int prioridade;
    int mesa, n_pratos;
    struct prato *prato[TAM];
    ppedido prox;
};

struct prato{
    char id[5];
};

int verifica_prato(char prato[])
{
    FILE *f;
    struct item aux;

    int i=0, j=0;

    f = fopen("menu.bin", "rb");

    while((fread(&aux, sizeof(struct item), 1, f)) == 1){
        if((strcmp(prato, aux.id)) == 0)
        i++;
    }
    fclose(f);

    if(i == 0){
        printf("Prato nao existe no menu.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if(i > 1)
        return 0;
    }
```

This is where the function ia called.

```
for(i=0;i<novo->n_pratos;i++){
    do{
        printf("Introduza o ID do prato %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%s", &novo->prato[i]);
        printf("%s", novo->prato[i]);
        k = verifica_prato(novo->prato[i]); //this function
        if(k == 0)
            w = verifica_ing(novo->prato[i]->id);
        }while(k != 0);
}
```

Comment: Can we see how novo is defined?

Comment: are you sure you are not entring more than 5 characters?

Comment: what should `pedido pedido` does mean?

Comment: `for(;;) {do {...} while(...); }` is definitely an anti-pattern, IMHO. Plus: remove the typedefs; You'll live longer.

Comment: It's a struct from type "pedido" with the name "pedido". They have the same name, so that could be confusing, sorry.

Comment: To what does `novo->prox` point?  (Or does this not matter, for some reason?)

Comment: One suspects that this is a homework question, not tagged as such.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/11161070/1275653 .  In the meantime, I have spent half an hour working on the code and, regrettably, it seems to too full of errors to make something sensible of.  Addresses are confused with their objects.  Members are confused with the types to which they belong.  A function is allowed to fall through without a return value.  Too full of errors.  Sorry, can't help.  (You might follow the link I have provided, though.  It seems to belong to a classmate of yours.)

Comment: @folex typedef struct foo foo is a pretty common idiom in C.

Comment: 'somewhere in the function call or the scanf before it' -- c'mon, you have to know which, you've got a printf between them! Look, I've written thousands of pieces of code like this and didn't have SO to run to to debug them. Do the hard work and figure it out yourself, and save SO for questions about programming that might be of value to someone other than yourself.

Comment: Thx, @JimBalter, I've just misread because of comma.

Answer (score 3):

Inside `verifica_prato()`
after the line `f = fopen("menu.bin", "rb")`  you should check whether the file opened successfully or not.
 use  `if( f != NULL )`

Answer (score 0):

Is `novo->n_pratos` always less than `TAM`? There could be a bounds error if it `n_pratos` exceeds `TAM`, because `TAM` has been defined as the array size.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt the signature of verifca_prato be int verifica_prato(struct prato) or the call should be verifica_prato(novo->prato[i]->id);